# Compilation fails in Xcode 4.6 while creating archive for adhoc distribution.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am new to iOS. and i am trying adhoc distribution ipa file from xcode.

1) I could able compile and run the application in the iphone/ipad.

2) But when i create archive, i am getting compilation error saying 'something.h' not found.

Could someone kindly direct me what could be wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you have a missing #include statement somewhere. Can you please edit your question and include the exact error to start?

Comment: Mountain/Mountain.h file not found is the error. But how come it is getting compiled while building/running in the device but not in the archive?.

Comment: In your project navigator (folder icon in the upper-left of the XCode environment) are those file names red or black?

Comment: Everything is black, no red color files :(.

Comment: Are you importing a framework into your project by any chance?

Comment: Yes, SBJson is what i m seeing.

Comment: Search your code for `DEBUG`, maybe you have a preprocessor macro like `#if DEBUG` somewhere that shouldn't be there.

Comment: if you search your project for "mountain" do you get any hits?

Answer (score 0):

1-Try to open the organizer (Window -> Organizer), then the Projects tab. Select your project then hit the delete button next to the derived data path (to the right). Confirm and let it re-index your project.

2-Go to your project folder, Press on YOURPROJECTNAME.xcodeproj and right click and go to show package contents . Leave the project.pbxproj file, but delete the project.xcworkspace file, any .pbxuser files, and the entire userdata folder.

I hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting things in a group in the XCode project navigator, and it is not an actual folder, you do not need to do `Mountain/Mountain.h`. You would just include `Mountain.h`.

When creating a group in the project navigator, by default, these are not actual folders, they are just *virtual* project folders, so if it is trying to see the Mountain folder and it does not exist, you will get that error.

It is weird that it will compile and run otherwise, but just give that a shot, let me know if it works.